# ColumnChart: how to get rid of shadow behind columns?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex4.6, flex-charting, flex-charts

I have few questions about [ColumnChart](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7c59.html) please (screenshot and code below):

[image]

1. How to get rid of the shadow drawn behind each column? I've tried adding `<mx:filters />` but it hasn't helped
2. How to get rid of the padding between columns, so that they touch each other sidewise (like stairs) **SOLVED**
3. How to get rid of the warning `Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "horizontalAxis"`? I've tried moving that code block around to get rid of the `axis` parameter, but can't find the right spot. **SOLVED**

   ```
       <mx:ColumnChart id="_chart"
               type="overlaid"
               dataProvider="{_ac}" >

   <mx:filters /> <!-- doesn't remove shadows -->

   <mx:horizontalAxis>
       <mx:CategoryAxis categoryField="yw"/>
   </mx:horizontalAxis>    

   <mx:horizontalAxisRenderers> <!-- warning -->
       <mx:AxisRenderer axis="{_chart.horizontalAxis}" canDropLabels="true" />
   </mx:horizontalAxisRenderers>       

   <mx:series>
       <mx:ColumnSeries 
           xField="yw" 
           yField="max" 
           displayName="Лидер недели"
           />
       <mx:ColumnSeries 
           xField="yw" 
           yField="pos" 
           displayName="Выигрыш"
           />
       <mx:ColumnSeries 
           xField="yw" 
           yField="neg" 
           displayName="Проигрыш"
           />      
   </mx:series>
       </mx:ColumnChart>

       <mx:Legend dataProvider="{_chart}" 
          direction="horizontal" 
          width="100%" />
   ```

**UPDATE**:

Sunil has helped with question #3, thanks!

And the problem #2 is solved by `columnWidthRatio="1"`

So now I just need to know, how to get rid of the shadows - as per question title :-)

Comment: For the warning about binding, add an id to the CategoryAxis: `<mx:CategoryAxis id="cateogryAxis" />`. Then use that id in the curly brace expression instead of "_chart.horizontalAxis": `<mx:AxisRenderer axis="{categoryAxis}" />`

Comment: Thanks, I was wrongly trying to add it to `horizontalAxis` before

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, simple add `seriesFilters="{[]}"` to `mx:ColumnChart` attributes.